# ReSharper for C# 7.0

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.0

I'm using `VS 2017` and `ReSharper Ultimate 2016.3.2`.

The code builds fine but in text editor I'm getting something like errors:
[image]

and

[image]

When I suspend `ReSharper` the errors are gone. What is the problem?

Comment: Looks like ReSharper is the problem. I'm not o ReSharper user but, as far as I know, support for C# 7 is still in preview.

Comment: @PauloMorgado [Do you know the latest news?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

Comment: @Pr.Dumbledor- Yes he knows the "latest" news. But the delivery of VS 2017 with C# 7 changes not the fact that Resharper has not shipped yet a final version to support VS 2017 and C# 7 . So errors are to expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initial support for `C# 7.0` was introduced [only a month ago](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/02/17/state-union-resharper-c-7-vb-net-15-support/) by Resharper team, so it's basically isn't ready:

> C# 7 and VB.NET 15 come with some additional language enhancements that we’re also adding support for in ReSharper but are **still in early stages in our nightly builds**

Right now these features are supported:

- `C# 7.0/VB.NET 15` binary literals and digit separators (parsing, several context actions, support for literals written in different base/separated differently)
- Support for `C#` local functions (parsing, analyzing null)
- Limited support for `C#` pattern-matching expressions (as the language design itself is not finished), `C#` output variables, `C#` tuples and `C#` deconstruction

There was a new release [earlier this week](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/03/20/resharper-ultimate-2017-1-eap-5/#more-14871), yet to support the features you're pointing to. So you should wait for a while.